# How the line element change in a complex change of variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, change-of-variable, conformal-field-theory

So I'm learning conformal field theory and having a hard time to prove the conformal Ward identity. From the lectures notes from John Cardy, he express the integral

$$ \delta S = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C T_{\mu \nu} \alpha^{\mu}\eta^{\nu}dl$$

in complex coordinates as

$$ \delta S = \frac{1}{2\pi i}  \int_C T(z)\alpha(z)dz + \text{ complex  conjugate}$$

My problem is how to change the expression of the line element $dl$ in the $x,y$ coordinates to its form in the $z, \bar z$ coordinates,  where $z = x +iy$ and $\bar z = x - iy$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if someone is gonna to pass by the same problem, but after a few tips from my professor I finally made it. The pdf with the answer is [here](https://animeis.life/JHmc7uPB.pdf). Would take to long for me to pass to math latex.

Comment: In the case you see my message, I am interested by your answer, but unfortunately the file is no longer where you posted it...

Comment: Hey Jean, I reuploaded the file in another platform.
Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides, my interest for Ward identities/methods has been triggered by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0506158.pdf)